# Proper framing on foundation?

Tags: framing, foundation, building-regulations

I think the foundation crew and the framing crew weren't on the same page. In the plans, this part of the home does not overhang the stick framing underneath. I'm not sure but I think the foundation was built short and the framers had to go past to accommodate the square footage.

QUESTION: Is this safe even though it is aesthetically not correct and does not follow the plans?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is called a cantilevered floor; the IRC section R502.3.3 stipulates conservatively that the span shouldn't exceed the floor joist depth, which looks to be about the case from the picture... but I'm just leaving this as a comment since I'm no structural engineer nor a carpenter. My house has cantilevered floors, intentionally, with a similar span. They do require proper insulating and venting.

Comment: Wouldn't the plans tell you whether this was a planned feature or not?

Comment: It's definitely not on the plans - it's a contractor mess-up.

Comment: The plans should be corrected to show the existing situation and any other required changes, because of it, implemented according to the (an) architect and any local building code dept.  Offhand, however, the cantilevering isn't dramatic but there will be some impact that should be made aware to all concerned.

Comment: Thanks, James. What is some possible impact of the cantilevering? I'm guessing that you are referring to a measurable downward force because of the overhang.